# How can I return DbSet<Entity> AsQueryable<EntityBase> in MVC4 api controller?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 and entity framework. I would like to have ApiController called UserController to query users based on their properties.
My User entity has properties like name, phone number, address (complex type) and it should be possible to query and retrieve users based on this data. But user has also properties like password, lastsync, etc. which I do not want to be visible. Currently I don't have a solution. The following gives me the users, but with all the entities, also the ones I don't want to show.

```
public class UserController : BaseApiController
{
    public IQueryable<User> Get()
    {
        // _db is my entity framework DbContext
        return _db.Users; 
    }
}
```

I thought I would move all the "publicly" visible properties to ApiUser class and make User derive from ApiUser. Then my idea was to do like this:

```
public class UserController : BaseApiController
{
    public IQueryable<ApiUser> Get()
    {
        return _db.Users.AsQueryable<ApiUser>(); 
    }
}
```

This unfortunately does not work I get the following exception:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The type Repository.User was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.]
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterDelegatingEnumerable1.Write2_ApiUser(String n, String ns, ApiUser o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType) +171
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterDelegatingEnumerable1.Write3_ArrayOfApiUser(Object o) +297
```

Do you know how I can achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a projection:

```
public IQueryable<ApiUser> Get()
{
    return _db.Users.Select(u => new ApiUser
    {
        Name = u.Name,
        PhoneNumber = u.PhoneNumber,
        Address = u.Address
    });
}
```

And don't derive `User` from `ApiUser` or the other way around.

You can add then - for example - `Where` extensions to the query:

```
ApiUser apiUser = Get().Where(au => au.Name == "John Doe").SingleOrDefault();
```